# Are These Minifig Helmet, Hair, and Stingray Accessories Official LEGO Parts?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, star-wars

I bought some minifigures on the internet, but these helmet, hair, and animal parts only have NUMBERS on them, but no *LEGO* logo.

They feel like *LEGO*, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know a way?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to BRICKS!

These are the four official LEGO parts you questioned.

Cross check their part numbers with the ones you've got on hand.

If they match, then they're good.

See ya!

***Part# 61189pb03.***

- [image]

***Part# 15083pb01.***

- [image]

***Part# 30084.***

- [image]

***Part# 43753.***

- [image]